# FireBug works but doesn't produce results in the console

Tags: firefox, javascript, console, firebug

When I execute any command, e.g. the very simple *console.log("hazaa")* I don't get the output in the console window. The same command on my other computers works well. It works on the regarded computer too when I execute it in Chrome. It's like if user-entered commands were disregarded.

So, apparently, something went bad with my FF. When JavaScript is executed by a site, it produces output to the console without problems, so the issue is limited to **this** particular computer, **this** particular browser and **the input method** by the user!

It's like if a setting "*don't respect input from user typing in the console*" was checked.   :)   Of course, I went through all the settings I could find, reinstalled FF (got the newest version - 26, I think, (re/un)installed FireBug, deactivated all other stuff, restarted the computer, preyed and cried - nothing helped...

What to do?! How to trouble-shoot it?!

Comment: Do you have other addons installed? If so, disable them. Otherwise, try this: https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Install_Firebug_into_a_clean_profile

Comment: I've tested to deactivate everything but to no avail. At the moment, the only addin I use (besides FireBug) is the TabMix, which is a life saver. I fear that if I install the new profile, all my settings, bookmarks etc. will be gone. What do you think?

Comment: @fflorent In any case, however, when I use the new profile, the problem perishes, so it **must** be some stupid setting that some stupid addin did and refuses to take back upon deactivation. Thanks for the help and put your comment (and possibly an elaboration) as a reply so I can check it as the correct answer, please. And by the way - is there a way to **remove** addins? Or are we supposed to simply deactivate and, when things get to tough, install a new profile?!

Comment: Have you looked in about:config and sort by "status"? Every preferences set by you or by an addon would be listed together and be displayed in bold

Comment: Oh, that was cool. Totally confusing and waaay to scary for me to play with (I'm a super hero and my super power is to screw up stuff, haha). But still - cool. I could compare the two configs, of course. And how about deleting (not just deactivating) plugins?

Comment: By the way - summarize that as a reply so I can check it as an answer, please.

Comment: Removing the addons might also work... Oh BTW, do you have errors related to Firebug when pressing CTRL-SHIFT-J ? (I'll summarize the answer afterwards)

Comment: When I press the key combination, I get the default developer tool and a bunch of warnings (no errors, though). If they're related to FireBug or not I can't tell. The page I'm opening is google.com so it **shouldn't** be wrong. On the other hand, one **shouldn't** drive over the speed limit and we know how that works, haha.

Comment: Well, Ctrl-Shift-J also logs exception thrown by the extensions. That doesn't seem your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here are the things to do in that case:

- Disable every addon you have except Firebug and see what happens
- Check that no exception related to Firebug is listed in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- Check that [installing Firebug with another profile](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Install_Firebug_into_a_clean_profile) helps